# Foreign key to a subset of rows?

Tags: database-design

I have a table of `Courses` and it has a foreign key to `Class_ID`.

A class teaches several courses dividing into several terms. So, `Terminal` is another table, it has a foreign key `Class_ID` to `class` table.

Each terminal (or term) has courses that need to be completed in that term. So, there is another join table `TermCourse` which has foreign_key to both `Course` table and `Terminal` table.

The problem is, I can input into `TermCourse` table a course, which is not listed for this class, hence shouldn't also be included for any of the terminal of this class.

How do I enforce that only a **subset of the courses** are eligible to be included into `TermCourse`, namely those ones who are already included for this class to which this terminal belongs to?

The tables are

```
Class
-------
Class_ID (Primary key)
Description

Course
-------  
Course_ID (Primary Key)
Course_Name  
Class_ID (Foreign Key to Class)  

Terminal 
-------- 
Terminal_ID (Primary key)
Terminal_No  
Class_ID(Foreign key to Class)

TermCourse (Join Table)
--------
Terminal_ID (Foreign key to Terminal)
Course_ID (Foreign key to Course)
```

Here is a diagram of this ER design

[image: e-r diagram picture]

Comment: Are you asking for a SQL query to find the "eligible" courses or for a design (how to store which courses are eligible for which term)?

Comment: for design. how to store which courses are eligible for each term.